# Insrting "N" number of formatted Rows when "N" placed inside a specific Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to generate N number of rows when the user enters number N into  cell D7. These rows need to formatted with borders. x1Thin

Whenever number N is changed the number of rows must also change

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question. • Hint: Start reading about the [Worksheet.Change Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change)

Comment: ***UNCLEAR*** .............At which position in your worksheet should the rows be inserted ???

Comment: `x1Thin` is not a border argument. Turn on `Option Explicit` and check your spelling.

Comment: Apologies, the rows should be inserted at A10:D10

Answer (score 0):

Put this behind the sheet object that you want it to run on

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim NoRows As Long

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D7")) Is Nothing Then
        With Me
            NoRows = .Range("D7").Value2
            ' Update with your reference to where the first row you want to change is
            With .Range("A1").Resize(NoRows)
                With .Borders
                    .Weight = xlThin
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                End With
            End With
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```